# Segmentation Fault with MPI_Gather

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, openmpi

I am using MPI_Gather for the first time and following some examples but for some reason I am getting a seg fault whenever I call it. The relevant code is here:

```
    //Get the top N matches for each node
    for (int j = 0; j < send_counts[id]; j++)
    {   
        data = read_file(my_dir + files[rec_buf[j]]);
        temp_results = circularSubvectorMatch(test_vectors[i], data, N); 
        results.insert(results.end(), temp_results.begin(), temp_results.end());
    }   

    std::sort(results.begin(), results.end(), sort_function);
    results.resize(N);

    //Send the N dissimilarities from each node to the root process and let it figure out
    //the Nth best one overall
    float *best_times = new float[N];
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {   
        best_times[j] = results[j].dissimilarity;
    }   

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    float *all_dissimilarities = NULL;
    if (id == 0)
    {   
       float *all_dissimilarities = new float[N * procs];
    }   

    MPI_Gather(best_times, N, MPI_FLOAT, all_dissimilarities, N, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    float *nth_best;
    if (id == 0)
    {
        std::sort(all_dissimilarities, all_dissimilarities + N * procs - 1);
        *nth_best = all_dissimilarities[N-1];
        *nth_best = 1.0;
    }
    MPI_Bcast(nth_best, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    cout << "My id is " << id << "and I received: " << *nth_best << endl;

    //each process prints each result it has that is better than or equal
    //to the Nth best result calculated by the root process


    //output search vector and search time

    free(all_dissimilarities);
    free(best_times);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I've allocated a send buffer and receive buffer like in the example, could anybody shed some light on why I might be getting this error?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you use std::vector in some places in the code, but don't use it for obvious things such as this: `float *best_times = new float[N];`  You then compound the issue by calling `free()` on memory allocated with `new[]`.  As it stands now, your code snippet introduces undefined behavior.

Comment: Well this is actually my first C++ class so I'ma  bit new to the language. This isn't the cause of the seg faults though right?

Comment: Your code introduces undefined behavior.  Anything can happen with such code.  My advice is to stop reading 'C' language books or 'C' related material, and start reading C++ books and material.  Also, since it is a snippet, we don't know what the values of j are, whether that files array is being accessed out of bounds, etc.

Comment: My suspicion is that this version is crashing because your root process declared `all_dissimilarities` twice; the second time, where memory is allocated (`float *all_dissimilarities = new float[N * procs];`) is in the if block and didn't affect the `all_dissimilarities` defined in the main function body, which remains NULL. Now why the vector version below is crashing, I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two issues, one that needs to be fixed, and another that will clean up your code.  Also, since we really don't know what the values of "j" are, then all I can do is assume that these values are valid.

The issues are as follows:

Issue 1:  Calling free() on data allocated with `new[]`.

Never mix allocation and deallocation functions like this.  If you allocate with `new[]`, you deallocate using `delete[]`, not `free()`, and not `delete`(non-array delete).

Issue 2: Using new[] when there is no need to use it.

You can replace all of those calls to new[] with std::vector.  Here is a rewrite of your code snippet using vector:

```
 //Get the top N matches for each node
#include <vector>
//...
typedef std::vector<float> FloatArray;
//...
for (int j = 0; j < send_counts[id]; j++)
{   
    data = read_file(my_dir + files[rec_buf[j]]);
    temp_results = circularSubvectorMatch(test_vectors[i], data, N); 
    results.insert(results.end(), temp_results.begin(), temp_results.end());
}   

std::sort(results.begin(), results.end(), sort_function);
results.resize(N);

//Send the N dissimilarities from each node to the root process and let it figure out
//the Nth best one overall
FloatArray best_times(N);
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    best_times[j] = results[j].dissimilarity;

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

float *pFirst = NULL;
FloatArray all_dissimilarities;
if (id == 0)
{
   all_dissimilarities.resize(N * procs);
   pFirst = &all_disimilarities[0];
}

MPI_Gather(&best_times[0], N, MPI_FLOAT, pFirst, N, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
float nth_best;
if (id == 0)
{
    std::sort(all_dissimilarities.begin(), all_dissimilarities.end());
    nth_best = all_dissimilarities.back();
    nth_best = 1.0;
}
MPI_Bcast(&nth_best, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
cout << "My id is " << id << "and I received: " << nth_best << endl;
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

There are now no calls to new[], no (erroneous) calls to free().  There is very little, if any pointer usage.  Since the vector knows how to destroy itself, there are no memory leaks.

Comment: I made these changes, I agree they definitely correct other errors but unfortunately they didn't solve my seg faulting problem.